# split string into list of tuples?

Tags: python, split, tuples

I have a string of key-value pairs, which unfortunately are separated by the same symbol. Is there a way to "just split" it into a list of tuples, without using a lambda?

Here is what i have:

```
Moscow|city|London|city|Royston Vasey|vilage
```

What i want:

```
[("Moscow","city"), ("London", "city")....]
```

Comment: I have tried writing a function that splits the string by the separators, and then iterates over it and yields two next elements in a tuple.

Comment: @Ibolit can you **show** what you tried in your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def group(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        val = lst[i:i+n]
        if len(val) == n:
            yield tuple(val)

a = 'Moscow|city|London|city|Royston Vasey|vilage'
list(group(a.split('|'), 2))
```

The output is `[('Moscow', 'city'), ('London', 'city'), ('Royston Vasey', 'vilage')]`

Answer (score 15):

This is a pretty easy one really...

first, split the string on `'|'` then `zip` every other element together:

```
data = s.split('|')
print zip(data[::2],data[1::2])
```

In python3, you'll need:  `print(list(zip(data[::2],data[1::2]))`

Answer (score 8):

```
s = 'Moscow|city|London|city|Royston Vasey|vilage'

it = iter(s.split('|'))
print [(x,next(it)) for x in it]
```

Comment: For forward-compatibility reasons, it's probably better to encourage `next(it)` rather than `it.next()`.

Comment: @DSM OK, thank you. Moreover ``next(it)`` is more clear. But what do you mean by froward-compatibility ? Relatively to passage to Python 3 ?

Comment: @eyquem, yes `.next` becomes `.__next__` in line with other methods like `__str__` and `__len__` etc.

Comment: @gnibbler OK thank you. I've seen in the Python 3 "s doc, next() has indeed disappeared as a method. - Just a point: "in line with other methods" means "as other methods", doesn't ?

Answer (score 7):

Python3:

```
>>> s = "Moscow|city|London|city|Royston Vasey|vilage"
>>> list(zip(*[iter(s.split('|'))]*2))
[('Moscow', 'city'), ('London', 'city'), ('Royston Vasey', 'vilage')]
```

Python2:

```
zip(*[iter(s.split('|'))]*2)
```

Comment: @NPE -- This one is pretty much straight from somewhere in the itertools documentation.  It ends up being useful at times though.

Comment: I +1 but this solution pleases me only at 3/4 because after the creation of list by ``s.split('|')`` and creation of the iterator ``iter(s.split('|'))``, another list of the same iterator repeated is created, then it needs an additional unpacking to on-the-fly parameters of zip

Answer (score 1):

You could use `city, status, remaining = s.split("|", 2)` and some recursive method `city_split(s)` to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Ibolit You should be aware that if there are N tuples to extract in the string, this solution creates N-1 strings named ``remaining`` having no real justification since there are other  ways to do without this.